# Python while loop string index out of range

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

I am looping a string in Python to append in a list the words between ";" (I know there are other ways to loop strings in Python but I want this to work):

```
data = "ABC;AB;AB"
data_len = len(data)
items = []
separator = ";"

i = 0
while i < data_len:
    item = ''
    if i == 0:
        while data[i] != separator:
            item += data[i]
            i += 1
        items.append(item)
        continue
    i += 1
    while data[i] != separator and i < data_len:
        item += data[i]
        i += 1
                    
    items.append(item)
```

The logic seems correct to me but somehow the interpreter throws an Index out of range exception:

> while data[i] != separator and i < data_len: IndexError: string index
> out of range

Comment: Because you increment i but still use afterwards and it causes an out of index error. Check your formatting because python indentation affects logic.

Comment: Use `while i < data_len and data[i] != separator:` rather than `while data[i] != separator and i < data_len:` (i.e. check that index is in range before using it).

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

The order of the 2nd inner while loop condition checks first the `data[i]` and then `i < len`

The solution is to interchange the conditions in the second loop from:

```
while data[i] != separator and i < data_len:
```

to:

```
while i < data_len and data[i] != separator:
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just a small mistake when last while loop was initiated. The `data[i] != separator and i < data_len`conditions must be swapped.

```
data = "ABC;AB;AB"
data_len = len(data)
items = []
separator = ";"

i = 0
while i < data_len:
    item = ''
    if i == 0:
        while data[i] != separator:
            item += data[i]
            i += 1
        items.append(item)
        #print(items)
        continue
    i += 1
    #print(i)
    while i < data_len and data[i] != separator:
        item += data[i]
        i += 1
                    
    items.append(item)
    #print(items)
```